# IIS Kerberos double hop not working for windows clients

Tags: php, iis, sql-server, authentication, kerberos

I have an IIS 7.5 server configured for Kerberos Authentication and this has been working fine for quite a while.

Recently, some Windows updates were applied (by server admins) and now when my IIS server connects to a remote SQL Server instance (double hop), the kerberos ticket isn't being passed to SQL Server - but *only* for Windows clients. When I connect with my Mac, everything works fine. I also know that the Kerberos ticket *is* being passed from the client because the site only authenticates via Kerberos (Authentication->Windows Authentication only -> Negotiate: Kerberos provider only) and I can echo out the username (this is with PHP, so `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`).

*Note:* This all worked fine before the updates were applied *and* everything still works when accessed from a Mac (specifically Safari).

No configuration changes were done to IIS, so I don't know where to start looking. I suspect there are a lot of possible places where the Kerberos might break and I need some help hunting that down.

Has anyone ever run into a problem like this before or have an idea where to start hunting down where something might have broken?